# How to Import products Excel file to Laravel project. I have tried several methods

Tags: excel, laravel, import

I am working the project need to upload the Excel file.  I have tried several methods.

Import Products  - Blade Page

[image: Product Import Page]

Controller Page

```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Support\Str;
  use App\Models\Products;
  use App\Models\ProductsImage;
  use App\Models\Year;
  use App\Models\VehicleMake;
  use App\Models\VehicleModel;
  use App\Models\Category;
  use App\Models\AppSettings;
  use Hash;
  use Session;
  use File;
  use Image;

    protected function importstore(Request $request)
      { 
        $request->validate(
        [  
        'uploaded_file' => 'required|max:50000',       
        'vehicle_make'=>'required',
        'vehicle_model'=>'required',
        'category'=>'required'
        ],[
        'vehicle_make.required'=>"This is a Required filed.",
        'vehicle_model'=>"This is a Required filed.",
        'category.required'=>"This is a Required filed.",
        'uploaded_file.required'=>"This is a Required filed."
        ]);

            $uploaded_file= $request->file('uploaded_file');
            $rows = $uploaded_file->toArray();
            foreach ($rows as $key=>$row) {
              $pdct_year_from  = $row[0];
              $pdct_year_to    = $row[1];
              $pdct_title      = $row[2];
              $pdct_sku        = $row[3];
              $pdct_details    = $row[4];

              $pdct_vehicle_make  = request("vehicle_make");
              $pdct_vehicle_model = request("vehicle_model");
              $pdct_category      = request("category");

              $slug = Str::slug($product_title, '-');

        //Code for Data Save Tables
              $dataproducts = new Products();
              $dataproducts->product_year_from = $pdct_year_from;
              $dataproducts->product_year_to = $pdct_year_to;
              $dataproducts->product_make_id = $pdct_vehicle_make;
              $dataproducts->product_model_id = $pdct_vehicle_model;
              $dataproducts->product_cid = $pdct_category;
              $dataproducts->product_title = $pdct_title; 
              $dataproducts->product_details = $pdct_details;   
              $dataproducts->product_sku = $pdct_sku; 
              $dataproducts->slug = $slug;     
              $dataproducts->save();  
       
           }

    if($dataproducts){
        return back()->with('success', 'Your Product has been successfully added.');
    }else{
        return back()->with('fail', 'Somthing wrong !!!, Please try again.');
        }         
}
```

Error Showing:

```
  BadMethodCallException
  Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::toArray does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

`toArray()` is a collection method. You cannot use it on the uploaded file.
Try to

`dd($request->file('uploaded_file'));`

so you can iterate each row

Comment: Hi, Can you please help the issue solve. any another method..

Comment: Try to dd that and post the result here so I can help

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TZhOXM4              Please check this link

Answer (score 0):

it's because you can't convert file to array ,if you upload csv file then you can read line by line and split each line to get data of each cell

but there is a very good package to do this stuff you can use

you can add this package to you project `composer require maatwebsite/excel`
in [this link](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html) you can see how to install this package

and you can see the [documentation of how to import excel in database](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/) in just 5 min

Comment: Hi, I have check the above link. But I have get the three variables from drop-down box, that files how to import the database.